# Escalabilidad Horizontal

Tags: mysql, apache

lo que pasa es que debo hacer escalabilidad horizontal por lo que usare dos maquinas virtuales (ubuntu) en donde en una instalare apache + php y en la otra maquina instalare el Mysql, mi pregunta es como configurar cada servidor para un entorno de sistema distribuido y luego adaptar un pequeño programa en php con base de datos en este entorno distribuido para que funcione, de antemano gracias por la atención prestada

Answer (score 0):

Los servidores Apache y MySQL no tienen por qué estar necesariamente instalados en la misma máquina. Desde PHP abres la conexión al servidor MySQL con la instrucción:

```
$db=new mysqli('ip_de_tu_host_mysql','root','password','db');
```